# WMI method fails only on 1 server

Tags: c#, wmi

I wrote an app that performs certain Windows sysadmin tasks on servers and is intended to be run when logged in a Domain Administrator.  It works fine on all servers but one.  For example, this code disables a Windows service:

```
ManagementObject mgmtObj; 
...   // set mgmtObj to the service
var ret = (uint) mgmtObj.InvokeMethod("ChangeStartMode", new[] { "Disabled" });
// ret is 2 on the problematic server, meaning access denied
// ret is 0 on all other servers, meaning success
```

What would cause this to only fail on one server?  The same domain admin is logged in on both.

Also, how do I get more detailed info beyond "access denied"? Access to what?

**EDIT:**

If I run the app on the problematic server "as administrator" it works.  However this is not necessary on the other servers.

Comment: Perhaps the other server does not have `WMI` enabled or turned on.. have you double checked to make sure that the other server is setup the same as the working ones within your domain..?

Comment: have you read this Microsoft article [WMI Trouble Shooting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx)